# How to use bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails gem on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have used the `bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails` gem to select a date and datetime in my rails app.

My current implementation is:

**HTML:**

```
f.input :date, as: :string, :input_html => { :id => "datepicker" }
f.input :datetime, as: :string, :input_html => { :id => "datetimepicker" }
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'L'});
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
  });
```

However, I have met some problem:

1.The datepicker for each id can only be use once, which means if I have two datepicker, I need to write two javascript code `$('#datepicker1').datetimepicker();` and `$('#datepicker2').datetimepicker();`
. Is there a better way to reuse the code?

2.the datetimepicker didn't pull out the select dialog, I use it for inputing the datetime type attribute. When I click the field, the date and time is automate input into the field, the select dialog didn't appear.

3.Is there a way that just select the time but with a default date to fill in the datetime type attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**try this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({});
</script>
```